# How to create a function that will return 1 if a number is prime, and return 0 if it is not prime on C programming

Tags: c

Given this main, how do I create a function IsPrime (int n) that will print 1 if the number is prime and 0 if it is not, without using a printf statement in IsPrime?

```
int n;

do {
    printf("Input a positive integer greater than 1: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n <= 1)
        printf("Invalid input. Try again.\n");
} while (n <= 1);


if (IsPrime(n))
    printf("%d is a prime number.\n", n);
else 
    printf("%d is not a prime number.\n", n);

return 0;
```

Comment: There are countless examples out there, have you searched for any? "prime number c" should give some good results

Comment: How do you check if a number is prime with a pencil and piece of paper? Once you know that, ylou can program it.

Comment: _"given this main"..._.  I do not see a `main()`.  Provide at least what you have tried, and place it into a [mcve].

Comment: Look at mathematical algorithms for checking whether an integer is a prime or not and try to implement one in C. If along the way you got stuck somewhere, come back and ask about a specific problem in your code.

Comment: thank you all for your comments! this is my first time asking so i am a newbie haha

Comment: Also read this: [ask]

Comment: seems like someone is trying to avoid homework!

Answer (score 3):

That funtion will look like:

```
int IsPrime(int n)
{
    // determine if the number is prime or not
    //...
    // if the number is prime then:
        return 1;
    // otherwise:
        return 0;
}
```

Determining "primeness" is on you.